# Sum of List must be 16

Tags: prolog

I am stuck in this problem for 2 hours now! My problem in prolog is I am thinking in a declarative way!
So my issue is to make prolog generate a list equal to N!  The size of list is 5.

```
somme([],0) :- !.
somme([X|L],S) :- somme(L,S1), S is S1+X.


generateList(L,RES) :- C1 is random(4)+1, 
              C2 is random(5)+1,
              C3 is random(6)+1,
              append(L,[C1,C2,C3],RES).


go(L) :- generateList([2,3],L), somme(L,S), S \==16, go(L).
go(L) :- generateList([2,3],L), somme(L,S), S == 16,write(L).
```

We suppose that the 2 first element are 2 and 3.

Comment: You are meant to think in a declarative way in Prolog. So that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your program, amended:

```
somme([],0).  /* the cut is useless, since [] and [X|L] are distinguished */
somme([X|L],S) :- somme(L,S1), S is S1+X.

generateList(L,RES) :- C1 is random(4)+1, 
              C2 is random(5)+1,
              C3 is random(6)+1,
              append(L,[C1,C2,C3],RES).

/* A variable can be assigned only once, then you must backtrack. */
/* So: repeat/0 introduces a backtrack point, going into a "failure driven loop" */
/* until the test succeeds */
go(L) :- repeat, generateList([2,3],L), somme(L,S), S == 16, !.
```

test run

```
?- go(L).
L = [2, 3, 2, 4, 5].

?- go(L).
L = [2, 3, 2, 3, 6].
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day. There is not another solution without using repeat?

Comment: Beacause If I want to show all the result what can I do in this case?

Comment: First of all, instead of random/1, you should use a deterministic generator, like between/3. Otherwise - I think - there is no easy way to break the *infinite* generation process

Comment: No, You are free to use what you want. if I use between what changes do I have make to get all possiblities?

Comment: take a look at bagof/3 or setof/3. Is it the same question as https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1721908/autres-langages/autres-langages/prolog/code-aleatoire-contraintes/ ?

Comment: It's ok I have juste replace random with between thanks again

Comment: @AdouaniRiadh: I would try to replace random/1 with between/3, remove the repeat/0 and the final cut in go/1 body, finally use setof/3, like `?- setof(L,go(L),All).`. Or get rid completely of go/1: `?- setof(L, (generateList([2,3],L), somme(L,16)), All).

Answer (score 4):

You could also use CLP(FD) to describe such lists:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

numbers(L) :-
   L=[2,3,_A,_B,_C],   % list has 5 elements and begins with 2,3
   L ins 0..16,        % the list elements are between 0 and 16
   sum(L, #=, 16).     % the sum of the list elements is 16
```

If you query this predicate you get residual goals as an answer because there is no unique solution to the predicate:

```
   ?- numbers(L).
L = [2,3,_A,_B,_C],
_A in 0..11,
_A+_B+_C#=11,
_B in 0..11,
_C in 0..11
```

Add label/1 to the query and you get all 78 solutions:

```
   ?- numbers(L), label(L).
L = [2,3,0,0,11] ? ;
L = [2,3,0,1,10] ? ;
L = [2,3,0,2,9] ? ;
...
```

You can collect all solutions by using bagof/3 like so:

```
   ?- bagof(L,(numbers(L), label(L)),Xs).
Xs = [[2,3,0,0,11],[2,3,0,1,10],[2,3,0,2,9],[2,3,0,3,8],[2,3,0,4,7],[2,3,0,5,6],[2,3,0,6,5],[2,3,0,7,4],[2,3,0,8,3],[2,3,0,9,2],[2,3,0,10,1],[2,3,0,11,0],[2,3,1,0,10],[2,3,1,1,9],[2,3,1,2,8],[2,3,1,3,7],[2,3,1,4,6],[2,3,1,5,5],[2,3,1,6,4],[2,3,1,7,3],[2,3,1,8,2],[2,3,1,9,1],[2,3,1,10,0],[2,3,2,0,9],[2,3,2,1,8],[2,3,2,2,7],[2,3,2,3,6],[2,3,2,4,5],[2,3,2,5,4],[2,3,2,6,3],[2,3,2,7,2],[2,3,2,8,1],[2,3,2,9,0],[2,3,3,0,8],[2,3,3,1,7],[2,3,3,2,6],[2,3,3,3,5],[2,3,3,4,4],[2,3,3,5,3],[2,3,3,6,2],[2,3,3,7,1],[2,3,3,8,0],[2,3,4,0,7],[2,3,4,1,6],[2,3,4,2,5],[2,3,4,3,4],[2,3,4,4,3],[2,3,4,5,2],[2,3,4,6,1],[2,3,4,7,0],[2,3,5,0,6],[2,3,5,1,5],[2,3,5,2,4],[2,3,5,3,3],[2,3,5,4,2],[2,3,5,5,1],[2,3,5,6,0],[2,3,6,0,5],[2,3,6,1,4],[2,3,6,2,3],[2,3,6,3,2],[2,3,6,4,1],[2,3,6,5,0],[2,3,7,0,4],[2,3,7,1,3],[2,3,7,2,2],[2,3,7,3,1],[2,3,7,4,0],[2,3,8,0,3],[2,3,8,1,2],[2,3,8,2,1],[2,3,8,3,0],[2,3,9,0,2],[2,3,9,1,1],[2,3,9,2,0],[2,3,10,0,1],[2,3,10,1,0],[2,3,11,0,0]]
```

With an additional goal length/2 you can count the number of the collected solutions:

```
   ?- bagof(L,(numbers(L), label(L)),Xs), length(Xs,Len).
Len = 78,
Xs = [[2,3,0,0,11],[2,3,0,1,10],[2,3,0,2,9],[2,3,0,3,8],[2,3,0,4,7],[2,3,0,5,6],[2,3,0,6,5],[2,3,0,7,4],[2,3,0,8,3],[2,3,0,9,2],[2,3,0,10,1],[2,3,0,11,0],[2,3,1,0,10],[2,3,1,1,9],[2,3,1,2,8],[2,3,1,3,7],[2,3,1,4,6],[2,3,1,5,5],[2,3,1,6,4],[2,3,1,7,3],[2,3,1,8,2],[2,3,1,9,1],[2,3,1,10,0],[2,3,2,0,9],[2,3,2,1,8],[2,3,2,2,7],[2,3,2,3,6],[2,3,2,4,5],[2,3,2,5,4],[2,3,2,6,3],[2,3,2,7,2],[2,3,2,8,1],[2,3,2,9,0],[2,3,3,0,8],[2,3,3,1,7],[2,3,3,2,6],[2,3,3,3,5],[2,3,3,4,4],[2,3,3,5,3],[2,3,3,6,2],[2,3,3,7,1],[2,3,3,8,0],[2,3,4,0,7],[2,3,4,1,6],[2,3,4,2,5],[2,3,4,3,4],[2,3,4,4,3],[2,3,4,5,2],[2,3,4,6,1],[2,3,4,7,0],[2,3,5,0,6],[2,3,5,1,5],[2,3,5,2,4],[2,3,5,3,3],[2,3,5,4,2],[2,3,5,5,1],[2,3,5,6,0],[2,3,6,0,5],[2,3,6,1,4],[2,3,6,2,3],[2,3,6,3,2],[2,3,6,4,1],[2,3,6,5,0],[2,3,7,0,4],[2,3,7,1,3],[2,3,7,2,2],[2,3,7,3,1],[2,3,7,4,0],[2,3,8,0,3],[2,3,8,1,2],[2,3,8,2,1],[2,3,8,3,0],[2,3,9,0,2],[2,3,9,1,1],[2,3,9,2,0],[2,3,10,0,1],[2,3,10,1,0],[2,3,11,0,0]]
```